# Pre-processing script not removing punctuation

Tags: python, string, nlp, nltk

I have a code which is supposed to pre-process a list of text documents. That is: Given a list of text documents, it returns a list with each text document pre-processed. But for some reason, it is not working to remove punctuation.

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
nltk.download("stopwords")
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('wordnet')


def preprocess(docs):
  """ 
  Given a list of documents, return each documents as a string of tokens, 
  stripping out punctuation 
  """
  clean_docs = [clean_text(i) for i in docs]
  tokenized_docs = [tokenize(i) for i in clean_docs]
  return tokenized_docs

def tokenize(text):
  """ 
  Tokenizes text -- returning the tokens as a string 
  """
  stop_words = stopwords.words("english")
  nltk_tokenizer = nltk.WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize
  tokens = nltk_tokenizer(text)  
  result = " ".join([i for i in tokens if not i in stop_words])
  return result


def clean_text(text): 
  """ 
  Cleans text by removing case
  and stripping out punctuation. 
  """
  new_text = make_lowercase(text)
  new_text = remove_punct(new_text)
  return new_text

def make_lowercase(text):
  new_text = text.lower()
  return new_text

def remove_punct(text):
  text = text.split()
  punct = string.punctuation
  new_text = " ".join(word for word in text if word not in string.punctuation)
  return new_text

# Get a list of titles  
s1 = "[UPDATE] I am tired"
s2 = "I am cold."

clean_docs = preprocess([s1, s2])
print(clean_docs)
```

This prints out:

`['[ update ] tired', 'cold .']`

In other words, it does not strip out punctuation because "[", "]", and "." all appear in the final product.

Comment: probably brackets are not seen as punctuation. You should try `if word not in string.punctation or not in '[{()}]' ` or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to search a word in punctuation. Obviously `[UPDATE]` is not a punctuation.

Try searching for punctuation in the text/replacing punctuation instead:

```py
import string


def remove_punctuation(text: str) -> str:
    for p in string.punctuation:
        text = text.replace(p, '')
    return text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = '[UPDATE] I am tired'
    print(remove_punctuation(text))

# output:
# UPDATE I am tired
```